# A plugin or template for a points based bartering website

Tags: templates, wordpress

Can anyone recommend a WordPress plugin or another template that provides the skeleton of a points-based bartering website?

I'm looking to create a website for musicians where certain specific services can be offered in exchange for points. Much like experts-exchange or similar.

Before I embark on coding this, I was thinking I should check before reinventing the wheel.

I'll be grateful if anyone can make some recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the timebank plugin http://www.time-bank.info/

Kind regards of Anne